# Should we change column from xmltype to clob? orcale11 to 19

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration, oracle19c

I am a junior DBA in a small gaming company, which recently decided to upgrade its Oracle servers from version 11 to 19.

From the day the company was founded, 10 years back, there is a major  oracle table that is responsible for all the registered users, and it has a special xmltype column, to which over the years any tag that suddenly became necessary was 'pushed' into it

For example, a D.O.B tag, a zip code, etc. was added over time, and of course EXTRACTVALUE was used to extract the requested tag, which often caused slowness.

As mentioned, the company recently decided to upgrade to Oracle19 and discussions have begun as to whether it is worthwhile to re-establish the column as a clob, which will assign the 'parser task' to the server side and not to the DB, and will also allow the insertion of significantly larger text sections, say, agreements.

If we put the migration process aside, and the assumption that this column will continue to be used for values ​​that are not critical for each user (therefore we do not create columns for them) is it correct to re-create the column as a clob? Is there another idea given the new possibilities that Oracle19 provides?

Answer (score 2):

While I cannot provide an objective, non-opinionated answer that describes the best way to store semi-structured data in Oracle, below is a quick description of the process you should go through to determine what works best for you.

1. For XML data, read the sections in the [XML DB Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/choice-of-XMLType-storage-and-indexing.html#GUID-F1EE5B88-69E1-47B4-97FC-92F184C0CBA1) that discuss the pros and cons of different storage mechanism.
2. Consider using JSON instead. The [JSON Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/store-and-manage-json-data.html#GUID-F5FFFBC6-6672-40D6-A0DE-D395570AC135) also describes different pros and cons of different storage mechanism.
3. If you have a choice between XML and JSON, you should probably choose JSON because Oracle is heavily investing in that data format. There are many new features designed for JSON but not for XML. (Although many of those new features are only available in versions 21 and 23.)
4. Always add a constraint to the database when possible. No matter how much you trust your application, you should almost always have the database parse the data and verify the format. This can matter especially during migrations, where you may perform unique transformations of your data, and find that a single invalid XML file breaks a lot of database queries. Storing valid XML shouldn't limit the size of the data - you should still be able to store large XML files in the database. (Unless there are other LOB column issues. For example, if there are weird custom storage parameters, or if you're using the old fashioned basic lobs instead of the new SecureFile lobs. If necessary, change your LOB storage types while upgrading.)